# Rails 3 - is link_to with parameters secure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As a general rule of thumb you aren't supposed to trust any input of data from users.  If you had a simple link_to with a parameter:

```
link_to "Click me", test_path(:my_param => "test")
```

The route might look like: example.com/test?my_param=test

How do I know if the param, or any injected data for that matter, is being filtered properly?  The Rails 3 API doesn't specify that it filters data that is passed to the controller, but I want to make sure that the params[:my_param] is filtered securely in the controller before I utilize the params data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#injection

Comment: As long as you use the framework properly and don't go around writing raw SQL and use the helpers provided, then filtering occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Rails framework doesn't secure things by default for `GET` request. link_to tag is sending a http get request.

If it is a `POST/PUT/DELETE` request then the Rails uses `protect_from_forgery` for verify the data sending url

However in your case, its not hard to write a simple method to verify your data for get requests ,

you could write a `before_filter` to check the sending parameters for a GET request

HTH

Comment: Perfect that is exactly what I was looking for.  A simple helper method with regex should be able to filter out unwanted data coming through a GET request.  Thanks again!